# Selfhosted MVC 5 Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hey there do you know how to run a MVC 5 Project without IIS or IIS Express local on your desktop ?

In ASP.NET vNext there is a WebListener which made that possible but I can't reorganice my project to ASP.NET vNext.

Is there any possibility running a MVC 5 Project as well as in ASP.NET vNext?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't look like the other answers actually answer your question. The short answer is no, you cannot self host MVC 5, since it is dependent on IIS. If you want a self hosted web application, you either have to port your existing application to, for example, Nancy, or wait for the release of MVC 6 which can indeed be self hosted. Alternatively, you can look into Web Api,  where the current version also can be self hosted.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [OWIN](http://owin.org). It allows to instantiate your own little web server within your own application.

This is already available within the .Net framework through the [`WebApp.Start()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.hosting.webapp.start.aspx) method.

You simply create a class that contains a matching `Configuration` method that fills up the `IAppBuilder` and then you're done.

```
public class OwinStartup
{
    private static IDisposable _Server;

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Formatters.Insert(0, new JsonpFormatter());
        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
    }

    public static void Start()
    {
        // If the Start() method throws an exception, the problem
        // is a missing right. The url has to be registered somewhere
        // deep down in windows and this is only allowed by the admin.
        // But you can change this rule to allow this registration for
        // anybody by running the below command within a command prompt
        // with admin rights:
        // netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:14251/ user=Everyone
        // Depending on your OS language the group name can differ.

        string baseAddress = "http://+:26575/";

        try
        {
            _Server = WebApp.Start<OwinStartup>(url: baseAddress);
        }
        catch (HttpListenerException ex)
        {
            _Log.Message(Severity.Fatal, "Could not start web api listener.", ex);
            _Log.Message(Severity.Notice, "This normally happens cause the application is not allowed to add a web listener.");
            _Log.Message(Severity.Debug, "Open up a command prompt with admin rights and execute the following command: \"netsh http add urlacl url="+ baseAddress +" user=Everyone\"");
        }
    }

    public static void Stop()
    {
        if(_Server != null)
        {
            _Server.Dispose();
            _Server = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is for WebAPI, not ASP.NET MVC